# How do you Disable Mipmaps in Blender 2.80

Tags: texturing

I have pixel art I want to put on a 3D object, but it is fuzzy due to mipmaps.  In 2.79 you disabled this in **user preferences** - **system** but there is no longer that option in blender 2.80.  How do I disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out.  You have to set the interpolation on the texture to closest, and under the render panel, film, you need to set the filter size to it's lowest setting.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and it has a solution on Blender 2.8. Go to *Edit > Preferences*, click *Viewport* tab and under *Quality > Viewport Anti-Aliasing* select  *No Anti-Aliasing*.

Also you can find the mip map option on the box right in texture properties> add texture properties >image >sampling and disable the mip map.